# Merge Image for keras trainning

Tags: keras, array-merge

I have a dataset which contain about 60000 image for train and 10000 for test and it took very long time for training purpose( I used keras). I wonder that are there anyways to merger these separate image into 1 train file and 1 test file in order to decrease training time (may be stored in csv or numpy array).Does it possible to train with this way? Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: In my experience, training is slower than loading. Saving images in numpy format will bring you a REALLY big file. --- But how are you loading your images?

Comment: Image that I used is only about 50x50 ( I resized it to 64x64). It took me about 12 hours on CPU to train 8k pics for training and 2k pics for testing. I also use Image Generator in Keras. Can Image Generator in keras make my model train slower ?